# docker_image ansible module error Failed to import docker-py even after installing on remote host

Tags: docker, ansible, ansible-2.x

I am trying to build my container image using docker_image module of Ansible.

**My host machine details:**

```
OS: Lubuntu 17.10
ansible 2.4.2.0
config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
configured module search path = [u'/home/myuser/.ansible/plugins/modules', u'/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible
executable location = /usr/bin/ansible
python version = 2.7.14 (default, Sep 23 2017, 22:06:14) [GCC 7.2.0]
```

**My Remote machine details:**

```
Remote OS: CentOS 7.2
Pip modules: docker-py==1.2.3 , six==latest
```

**My tasks inside playbook:**

```
 - name: Install dependent python modules
   pip:
     name: "{{item}}"
     state: present
   with_items:
    - docker-py

 - name: Build container image for api
   docker_image:
      name: api
      path: /home/abc/api/ #location of my Dockerfile
```

However i am constantly getting the following error message:

```
"msg": "Failed to import docker-py - No module named 'requests.packages.urllib3'. Try `pip install docker-py`"
```

I see there is some issue with the docker-py module and also some solutions and fixes into ansible docker_container is also merged in the following links:

https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/20492

https://medium.com/dronzebot/ansible-and-docker-py-path-issues-and-resolving-them-e3834d5bb79a

I even tried with the following command to run my playbook:

```
python3 ansible-playbook main.yml
```

None of the above helped to resolve it successfully yet. How should i go about this now

Comment: Have edited the content for with tasks instead of playbook

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for this is as follows:

```
- name: Install dependent python modules
  pip:
    name: "{{item}}"
    state: present
  with_items:
    - docker-py==1.10.6
    - docker-compose==1.9.0
```

It works with the above versions of docker-py and docker-compose.
Reference for more info: 
https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/20380[1](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/20380)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to `docker-py` install the following packages:

```
- requests 
- urllib3
```

Comment: Still the same error. I suspect there is some dependency with some specific version of docker-py.

Answer (score 0):

docker-py module has some requirements modules in specific version.

Uninstall you current docker-py with pip and reinstall it with pip again on the remote host.`pip uninstall docker-py` and after `pip install docker-py`

I had the same problem with docker.py and docker-compose.py

Comment: This I have tried already and it doesn't work with the version of ansible I am using.